# Is there any alternative to creating Parent Package variable in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have three SSIS solutions each containing around 50 packages each. Each package has got a Master package where the Server name is hard coded and this variable is called by the child packages of respective solution. The Master package of each solution is called by a job. And of course, it is of Package Deployment model.
This was working fine when it was in 2008 version but lately after migrating to 2017 the child packages are unable to get the variable which it was supposed to fetch from the parent package and as a result the job is failing. I have hard coded the server name in each of the variables of each  package for one solution and it worked. But it is not possible to hard code for the all the packages of all the solutions. 
So my question is there any other way I can make it work? Convert to project deployment model? or any other less time consuming solution?
Keep in mind I have just mentioned about one such variable but in reality there are other variables present there too which serves the same purpose. The number of such variables vary from solution to solution according to their need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate to Project Model. Advantages of this approach:

1. Calling packages from the same project is straightforward - all you need to specify the package name in the project.
2. All packages can share Project parameters, which are read-only variables available in all packages. You can set project parameters at Master package start, or configure it to be copied from [SSIS Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/create-and-map-a-server-environment?view=sql-server-2014).

Project Mode is a good step forward compared to Configs of SSIS 2008 packages. The only downside -- Execute Package task calls packages from the same Project without trouble. Starting packages from other Projects (Project other than that of calling package) is not that straightforward and you have to do some tricks.

SSIS Environments allow to maintain configurations, with server names, connection strings etc specific to your environment. For example, task of maintaining Dev, QA and Prod environment settings is much easier with it than with old good Config files.

Comment: After converting to project deployment model, it sounds like the OP would be best served by creating a Project level connection manager and then ripping out all the logic for inheriting the connecting string. And then the SSIS environments makes it even easier for managing resources.

Comment: @Ferdipux looks like Project model is the answer to my problem. But can you explain this line in your answer- 'The only downside -- inside package it is no so easy to start package from external Project (Project other than that of calling package).'
Sorry if it is a noob question, but can't help it after I am a newbie in MSBI

Comment: @AlapanBag, changed wording to describe it better. In a nutshell -- calling a Package from other Project is not that straightforward.

Comment: @Ferdipux  Thanks a lot! That explains it.

Comment: @Ferdipux I was thinking that what if I change it to project model and only parameterize the variables which are needed(e.g. the server name) and keep all other variables as it is(fetching value from SSISConfigurations table). Is it a viable option?

Comment: @AlapanBag, No. *Package Configurations* are only available in Package Deployment mode. So, you have to migrate all the config variables to either Project or Package params. Or - read params from SQL SSISConfigurations table with SQL Task, but this means major package change.